# iOS simulator crash in iOS 8.2 and Xcode 6.2 with "Failed to lookup the process ID of #ID after successful launch."

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, xcode-6.2, ios8.2

iOS simulator crash in iOS 8.2 and Xcode 6.2 with an error below

"Failed to lookup the process ID of xxx.xxx.xxx after successful launch.  Perhaps it crashed after launch. No such process".

And I cannot try to simulate my app.

I uploaded the image of error.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mM2sV.jpg

It works normally when i use iOS 8.1 as a simulator. Regardless of the types of devices and types of projects, it will crash in iOS 8.2 simulator.

The iOS simulator itself stands but has nothing on the screen.

A thing I care is that I changed my old macbook to new one and copy project files of Xcode from old to new.

Do you have any idea of this?..

Comment: Will you please reset your Simulator of `iOS 8.2 simulator. like From Menu -> iOS Simulator -> Reset Content and Settings.

Comment: I've already tried that but nothing change.. Thanks.

Comment: This is solved by Xcode re-install. Thanks.

Answer (score 28):

I had the same problem and solved it by **force quitting and restarting** Xcode and iOS Simulator.

Comment: This worked for me, but a force quit was not necessary. A simple quit/restart did the trick.

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem after I did a Mac update on xcode. I had the IOS simulator open during the install/update process. When I closed it, re-ran my compile, it re-opened the simulator and ran fine.

Answer (score 3):

**Simulator -> Reset Content and Settings** did it for me.

Comment: Many quits and restarts didn't work, this did, specifically for running a tvos application on the Apple TV Simulator in case that is pertinent.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, all I needed to do was: Hardware -> Reboot on simulator.

Comment: Reset Content & Settings wasn't doing the trick for me, but this answer nailed it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, in my case the issue was :-

Have set "Build active architectures : NO". Just changed it to YES and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Even i had the same issue when i upgraded Xcode to 6.3.2. I just did re launch of Xcode and iPhone Simulator and worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using xcode 7 beta 2 and am having the same problem.

My take is that this is a random error probably due to a race condition.

If I start xcode, then simply run my app over and over again, the error occurs randomly. Typically it will work 1 to 3 times in a row and then will fail 1 to 3 times in a row. The most consecutive failures I have seen so far is 3.

Answer (score 0):

It might be the case that your app is not set up to build for the proper platform for simulator which are i.e. i386, x86_64.

It happened to me as I built for arm64 platform, and try to hook it up to simulator; built via `xcodebuild` command line. But I think you might want to try because basically Xcode use that tool to build things up for you.

So check the following in Build Setting of Xcode (along the line of text similar to this)

- Only Build Active Arch => YES
- Build architecture => i386 (or set to something else but not for mobile architecture)