# iPhone Simulator–App crashes on launch. Failed to lookup the process ID after successful launch. Perhaps it crashed after launch

Tags: ios-simulator

I already tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29714216/ios-simulator-crash-in-ios-8-2-and-xcode-6-2-with-failed-to-lookup-the-process).

When I try to use

```
xcrun simctl launch com.xxx.yyy
```

To launch an iPhone app from the Terminal, using iPhone simulator,
It crashes:

```
Failed to lookup the process ID of com.xxx.yyy after successful launch.  Perhaps it crashed after launch.
```

Amazing observation. `Perhaps it crashed after launch.` Very good observation.

Comment: What is your confusion?  What is the problem?  The system reported that your app crashed at launch (or exited on its own very quickly).  We can't really help you if you don't provide your crash log or more information.

Comment: That does not answer any of my questions nor provide additional context.  Please answer my questions above.  If you want help figuring out why your app ceashed, start by providing source and a crash log.

Comment: I don't have a crash log. I'm using iPhone simulator

Comment: And when your app crashes in the simulator, a crash log will be written to ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports

Comment: You can also use --wait-for-debugger to cause your app to launch suspended, such that you can attach to it with lldb to resume it and debug that way.